Error 500 running react-native expo app on Windows
I've developed a mobile app with expo (react-native) in TypeScript. In macOS it works well, I can run it with npx expo start and it renders fine in both Android and iOS.
Today I tried to run it from my Windows laptop and I've got an issue when trying to run npx expo start:
Android Bundling failed 53112ms (C:\Users\knocte\Documents\Code\BreakOrBuild\BreakOrBuildHabit\node_modules\expo-router\entry.js)
Unable to resolve "@react-native-picker/picker" from "node_modules\react-native-picker-select\src\index.js"

It seems that because of this issue, the app cannot run in Android (maybe iOS too, I haven't tried yet). The error that shows in Android starts with "The development server returned response error code: 500"
How to fix this? The interesting thing is that I think I also got a warning related to the picker when populating my dependencies. I think the warning said that I was using a deprecated community-based picker and that it had been migrated to https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker .
How to change my dependencies to point to the new picker and remove the old one? Will this solve my problem when launching the app on Windows?

I finally fixed it, I was using mistakenly using react-native-picker-select.
The diff to fix this was something like this:
diff --git a/BreakOrBuildHabit/package-lock.json b/BreakOrBuildHabit/package-lock.json
index d295ee8..9489bc7 100644
--- a/BreakOrBuildHabit/package-lock.json
+++ b/BreakOrBuildHabit/package-lock.json
@@ -11,9 +11,10 @@
         "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
         "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
         "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
+        "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.7.5",
         "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.10",
         "date-fns": "^3.3.1",
@@ -28,7 +28,6 @@
         "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
         "react-native-pager-view": "^6.2.3",
         "react-native-picker": "^4.3.7",
-        "react-native-picker-select": "^9.0.1",
         "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
         "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
         "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
diff --git a/BreakOrBuildHabit/components/HabitEdit.tsx b/BreakOrBuildHabit/components/HabitEdit.tsx
index d226b3c..edaac81 100644
--- a/BreakOrBuildHabit/components/HabitEdit.tsx
+++ b/BreakOrBuildHabit/components/HabitEdit.tsx
@@ -2,7 +2,7 @@
 import React, { useState } from 'react';
 import FontAwesome from '@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome';
 import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, Pressable, Modal, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
-import RNPickerSelect from 'react-native-picker-select';
+import { Picker } from '@react-native-picker/picker';
 import { Habit } from './Habit';
 
 interface ModalProps {
@@ -59,12 +59,16 @@ function HabitEdit ({habit, modalVisible, onClose}: ModalProps){
                     </View>
                     <Text style={styles.subHeading}>How often do you want to do it?</Text>
                         <View style={styles.dropdownContent}>
-                            <RNPickerSelect 
-                                placeholder={placeholder}
-                                items={options}
-                                onValueChange={(value) => { setTimeUnit(value) } }
-                                value={habit.timeUnit}
-                            />
+                            <Picker
+                                placeholder="Choose your frequency:"
+                                onValueChange={(value:string) => { setTimeUnit(value) } }
+                                selectedValue={habit.timeUnit}
+                            >
+                                <Picker.Item label="per day" value="per day" />
+                                <Picker.Item label="per week" value="per week" />
+                                <Picker.Item label="bi-weekly" value="bi-weekly" />
+                                <Picker.Item label="per month" value="per month" />
+                            </Picker>
                             <View>
                                 <FontAwesome name="caret-down" size={20} color="#303c6c" />
                             </View>

